# how do i maintain previous and current received data arrays with out getting out of bounds in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

so i am maintaining previous and current received data from textbox, by putting received data into an array, but when splitting them up using split() one of my newPosition arrays does not work, triggers "Index was outside the bounds of the array" but the other oldPosition works fine. Im abit stuck

here is my current implmenetation

```
           for (i = 1; i < textBox_ReceievedData.Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                currentPos = textBox_ReceievedData.Lines[i];
                prevPos = textBox_ReceievedData.Lines[i - 1];
              
                System.Console.WriteLine("array pos " + i);
                System.Console.WriteLine("previous array " +prevPos);
                System.Console.WriteLine("current Array " + currentPos);


                oldPosition = prevPos.Split(delimiterChars);
                newPosition = currentPos.Split(delimiterChars);

                System.Console.WriteLine("op " + oldPosition[2]);// used to get value in 2nd postition
            //System.Console.WriteLine("np " + newPosition[2]);// used to get value in 2nd postition, but will get an error
}
```

output:

```
array pos 2
previous array $GPGGA,090156.80,3651.09301173,S,17445.84851186,E,1,05,2.87,038.38,M,-21.3213,M,,*63
current Array $GPGGA,090157.00,3651.09230339,S,17445.84886368,E,1,05,2.87,038.33,M,-21.3213,M,,*6D
op 3651.09301173
array pos 3
previous array $GPGGA,090157.00,3651.09230339,S,17445.84886368,E,1,05,2.87,038.33,M,-21.3213,M,,*6D
current Array $GPGGA,090157.20,3651.09159552,S,17445.84921771,E,1,05,2.87,038.29,M,-21.3213,M,,*68
op 3651.09230339
```

if i were to use System.Console.WriteLine("np " + newPositon) i would get,

```
System.String[]
```

Comment: it means there is no index 2 exist in newPosition. that is it has only 2 element.

Comment: you do not have values after split

Comment: if i were to use  System.Console.WriteLine("np " + newPositon) i would get, System.String[]

Comment: @Cherios I just checked , you code is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked , Your code is working fine. it seems input is having incorrect format. plz put a if condition to check whether index exist or not like as below:

```
if (newPosition.Length > 2)
 {
  System.Console.WriteLine("np " + newPosition[2]);
 }
```

Output Here:
[image]